# Retrieve value of a category's custom field

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

Using the 'Advanced custom fields' plugin I have added a field to every post category that is called 'color' and it works just fine.

Now inside the loop I need to retrieve the value of the 'color' field, I have followed many other tutorials, but I could not achieve the result needed.

Here is the exaple of how the loop is set up:

```
    while ( $projects->have_posts() ) {
        $projects->the_post();

        $category_classes = array();
        $categories = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'project_category' );
        if ( $categories ) {
            foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
                $categories_included[] = $category->term_id;
            }
        }
```

Now in perfect scenario, I need to get the 'color' of a category inside the foreach loop.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/ prety much covers what you're after I believe.

So in your example

```
while ( $projects->have_posts() ) {
    $projects->the_post();

    $category_classes = array();
    $categories = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'project_category' );
    if ( $categories ) {
        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
            $categories_included[] = $category->term_id;
            $color = get_field('color', 'project_category_'.$category->term_id);
        }
    }
```

You can also pass a term to get_field and the_field, so you could also use the following depending on your version of ACF as I believe much older versions don't support passing terms

```
$color = get_field('color', $category);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, sencond solution with simply passing field name and category works perfect.